# Sorting a knowledge database in Prolog

Tags: prolog

It's my first day with Prolog, and i need some help.
I have a Konwledge database of students **student(Id,fName,lName,grade)**, I would like to display the list of students in order of merit, I have some ideas but I can not realise theme since I'm not familiar at all with prolog programming paradigm and syntax.
please recommend me a code that do this.

Comment: The first recommendation is to spend several hours reading a book about Prolog. Most university libraries have them. See also https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prolog/prolog_tutorial.pdf. For further questions provide some [mre]

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch  thank you sir, I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
student(1, sleve, mcdichael,4).
student(2, darryl, archideld,2).
student(3, mario, mcrlwain, 1).
student(4, bobson, dugnutt, 3).
student(5, dean, wesrey, 6).
student(6, mike, truk, 5).
student(7, dwigt, rortugal, 7).

sortedStudents(SortedStudents) :-
    findall(Grade-First-Last,
            student(_, First, Last, Grade),
            StudentData),
    sort(1, @=<, StudentData, SortedStudents).
```

Uses [findall/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) to get all the student records and turn them into a compound term of grade-firstname-lastname and [sort/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4) (might be SWI Prolog specific) to sort by term entry 1 (grade):

e.g.

```
?- sortedStudents(S).

S = [
1-mario-mcrlwain,
2-darryl-archideld,
3-bobson-dugnutt,
4-sleve-mcdichael,
5-mike-truk,
6-dean-wesrey,
7-dwigt-rortugal
]
```